# TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len() in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code first:

```
res = []

for x in range(9):

    if x == 0:
        res.append([1])
    elif x == 1:
        res.append([1,1])
        print(res)
    else:
        l=[]
        for y in range(len(res[x-1])):
            if y == 0:
                l.append(1)
            else:
                l.append(res[x-1][y] + res[x-1][y-1])
    l.append(1)
    res.append(1)
```

and I meet the problem. Then I change a little bit of code like this:

```
res = [[1],[1,1]]

for i in range(2,9):
res.append([1])
for j in range(len(res[i-1])):
    if j > 0:
        res[i].append(int(res[i-1][j-1]+res[i-1][j]))
res[i].append(1)
print(res)
```

and the error has gone.
I am quite wondering what is wrong inside?

Comment: You have `res.append(1)` your first version. That means `res` contains an int. So `len(res[x-1])` is trying to get the length of an int, which is the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have `my_var = 5`. By running `len(my_var)` you will get an error, because variable `my_var` is an int (short for an integer).

However, if you have `my_var = [5]`, your command `len(my_var)` will work because it is a list.

Similarly in your code, as khelwood says, if you have `l.append(1)`, your variable `l` will contain an integer 1. This will raise an error if you call `len()` on this element. If you want to append something to a list then find its length later, make sure it is not an int but a list, try `l append([1])`.